# I Have Created Laravel and reactjs project separately how to upload it on live cpanel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, cpanel

I am uploading my reactjs on my domain root directory but it is not fetching the apis of my backend which I have created on laravel.

Comment: With the amount of information you provided we know less than you know about what the problem might be. It would be useful to know if there are e.g. any errors fetching from the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue you have to store the laravel project in your root directory in different folder and for the frontend make the build first then copies all build file in root directory of your domain and make .htaccess file ,and alos change your apis url to your as per your new laravel routes.